# What do flanged power inlets attach to?

Tags: electrical

What does a flanged inlet like the one in the picture mount on/attach too?

I need to mount it on a 1 or 2 gang standard receptacle box. Does it need a certain type of mounting plate?

[image: image description]

Comment: Indoor or outdoor?

Comment: A male plug like that would almost never be mounted on a gang receptacle box, unless that box was the permanently mounted *input* to some piece of equipment which has a detachable cord. For safety reasons, plugs/receptacles are always installed such that the male end is the one which is not connected to live power without having been plugged-in. This is so that no live conductors are exposed and easily touched.

Comment: Outdoor would be better. This is intended as an inlet to get power into a work trailer from a temporary power pole, so no mains, just a cord from the temp power receptacle to the trailer inlet, which has female receptacles and lights inside.

Comment: @makyen it's for a power input to a structure or machine.  It will either feed the input lugs of a service panel, or backfeed a "generator breaker" that is interlocked with the main. There's nothing weird about mounting it in a standard junction box.

Comment: @Harper As I said, if it's for an input, then that's a reasonable thing to do. I've seen equipment which uses a standard junction box for that purpose. However, IMO, it's more likely that someone who is wanting to do that already knows more about doing it than is implied by this question. Thus, I felt it appropriate to provide a note of caution, indicating that the OP, or anyone reading this, should seriously consider if that is the appropriate connector to be using. By far, most people who are putting things in a "1 or 2 gang standard receptacle box" are thinking about outputs, not inputs.

Comment: Perhaps I used phrasing which is a bit too strong; or it's that the OP saying "inlet" doesn't inherently mean to me that they are using it as an input instead of an output; or, it's just that I've seen way too many people do things which are just very, very wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Flanged devices like that would usually be mounted to a piece of equipment, a hole would be cut in the panel of the equipment and then the flange would be screwed/bolted to the panel .

Physically you could almost certainly cut a hole in a blank box cover and then bolt the inlet to it. Whether that would comply with regulations in your country or whether you need to look for an inlet that is specifically designed for installation rather than equipment use I could not say.

Answer (score 3):

There are several "listed" methods for mounting flanged devices, you can use a box cover single gang for a 20 amp device as shown but I like double gang boxes to provide enough space. When I am adding a generator I will usually use a hole saw / or knockout set to create the correct size hole. I do not like using pre punched tko holes as these inlets get used they get weak and sometimes break out.

Answer (score 0):

This fits in a round hole for a 250 volt 20 amp supply cord to plug into a specific tool/ device or piece of equipment. It's handing if you ever need it. Namaste.